# Retrieve a variable from child job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that is reused/called from two parent jobs, I need to retrive a variable from this job to use it in each parent job.
The shell variable is a list of artifacts with size and md5sum.

The goal is to use this list in Editable email notification.

how I can retrieve it, let's call it ${artifacts_list}.

Thank you,

Comment: Is the job a downstream job of the other two?

Comment: @Technext yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although i have not tested it, you can try this approach: You can `echo` the variables and their values in a file (`name=value`) and read the file in your parent job. For making those variables available in your parent job's environment, you might need [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

A cumbersome way is to use the Jenkins API to read the `JSON` of the other job's specific run, and extract the parameters from it.

An easier way is to:

- Export job's parameters to file (use **[Export Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Export+Parameters+Plugin)** for that, or simply `echo` out the required param in format `param=value` like the other answer suggested)
- Archive the exported parameters file at the end of the build using "Archive Artifacts" post-build action
- In the downstream job, use **[Copy Artifacts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)** plugin to bring in that file
- Use **[EnjInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** plugin to read the file and make it available as environment variables.